# How can I use std::imbue to set the locale for std::wcout?

Tags: c++, c++11, locale

I am trying to use the `std::locale` mechanism in C++11 to count words in different languages.  Specifically, I have `std::wstringstream` which contains the title of a famous Russian novel ("Crime and Punishment" in English).  What I want to do is to use the appropriate locale (`ru_RU.utf8` on my Linux machine) to read the stringstream, count the words and print the results. I should also probably note that my system is set to use the `en_US.utf8` locale.

The desired result is this:

```
0: "Преступление"
1: "и"
2: "наказание"

I counted 3 words.
and the last word was "наказание"
```

That all works when I set the global locale, but not when I attempt to `imbue` the `wcout` stream.  When I try that, I get this result instead:

```
0: "????????????"
1: "?"
2: "?????????"

I counted 3 words.
and the last word was "?????????"
```

Also, when I attempt to use a solution suggested in the comments, (which can be activate by changing `#define USE_CODECVT 0` to `#define USE_CODECVT 1`) I get the error mentioned in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615136/is-codecvt-not-a-std-header).

Those interested in experimenting with the code, or with compiler settings or both may wish to use [this live code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d7bc409f511b0ae).

### My questions

1. Why does that not work?  Is it because `wcout` is already open?
2. Is there way to use `imbue` rather than setting the global locale to do what I want?

If it makes a difference, I'm using g++ 4.8.3. The full code is shown below.

### getwords.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>

#define USE_CODECVT 0
#define USE_IMBUE   1

#if USE_CODECVT
#include <codecvt>
#endif 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
#if USE_CODECVT
    locale ru("ru_RU.utf8", 
        new codecvt_utf8<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, consume_header>{});
#else
    locale ru("ru_RU.utf8");
#endif
#if USE_IMBUE
    wcout.imbue(ru);
#else
    locale::global(ru);
#endif
    wstringstream in{L"Преступление и наказание"};
    in.imbue(ru);
    wstring word;
    unsigned wordcount = 0;
    while (in >> word) {
        wcout << wordcount << ": \"" << word << "\"\n";
        ++wordcount;
    }
    wcout << "\nI counted " << wordcount << " words.\n"
        << "and the last word was \"" << word << "\"\n";
}
```

Comment: Try installing a utf8 converting facet into the locale: `locale ru{"ru_RU.utf8", new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, std::consume_header>{}};`. This requires the `<codecvt>` header.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't compile here.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615136/is-codecvt-not-a-std-header) for my exact symptoms.  I don't know of a workaround using g++.

Comment: UTF-8 is not locale-dependent. It can represent any Unicode codepoint, used by any language. I don't think the problem lies in the conversion performed by `wcout`. I'd check two things. First, whether the string literal makes its way into the binary intact. Do `wcout << (int)L'П';` - this should print `1055`; if it doesn't, the character is mangled by the compiler. Second, whether the console is set up to display non-English characters. Redirect output to a file, examine it with hex viewer. Cyrillic `'П'` should be represented as two bytes `D0 9F`

Comment: Redirecting the output to a file makes no difference, and the characters are correctly represented in the string. I added a new last line to the program `wcout << "The first letter of the last word is U+0" << hex << (int)(word[0]) << " (" << word[0] << ")\n";` which prints `The first letter of the last word is U+043d (?)`

Comment: @0x499602D2 I'd prefer a non-Boost answer, but any answer would be appreciated.

Comment: `Redirecting the output to a file makes no difference` What byte(s) appear in the file where `П` should be?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: a single byte `3f` which is corresponds to the `?` character.

Comment: Just to be sure, what OS are you using, and if under Windows what version ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta: I'm using Linux 3.16.4, Fedora 20 distribution.

Comment: To confirm: you did `wcout << (int)L'П';` and it printed `1055`?  Your print statement checks the state of the `wstring` after it round-trips through a `wstringstream` you have `imbue`d, which is a different test.  ("the characters are correctly represented in the string" might imply this, but it does not say what you did to determine they where correctly represented)

Comment: @Yakk: Yes, it printed 1055.  You can also demonstrate this for yourself by using this live code as posted in the question: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d7bc409f511b0ae

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In this answer, I'm taking the questions in reverse order, and adding another (with answer) that came up along the way.

### Is there way to use `imbue` rather than setting the global locale to do what I want?

**Yes.** By default, `std::wcout` is synchronized to the underlying `stdout` C stream.  So `std::wcout` *can* use `imbue` if that synchronization is turned off, allowing the C++ stream to operate independently.  So to modify the original code to use `imbue` and work as intended only a single line need be added, calling [`std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio):

```
std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
std::wcout.imbue(ru);
```

### Why didn't the original version work?

The standard (I'm referring to INCITS/ISO/IEC 14882-2011[2012]) says very little about the tie to the underlying `stdio` stream, but in 27.4.3 it says

> The object `wcout` controls output to a stream buffer associated with the object `stdout`, declared in `<cstdio>`

Further, without explicitly setting a global locale, the locale is the `"C"` locale which is US English ASCII, so this appears to imply that `stdout` will, by default, have an ASCII mapping.  Since no Cyrillic characters are represented in ASCII, the underlying `stdout` is what converts the proper Russian into a series of `?` characters.

### Why must the `sync_with_stdio` call precede `imbue`?

According to 27.5.3.4 of the standard:

> If any input or output operation has occurred using the standard streams prior to the call,
>   the effect is implementation-defined. Otherwise, called with a false argument, it allows the standard streams to operate independently of the standard C streams.

Answer (score 18):

First I did some more test using your code and I can confirm that `L"Преступление и наказание"` is a correct UTF16 string. I controlled the code of the individual characters, and they are correctly `0x41f, 0x440, 0x435, 0x441, 0x442, 0x443, 0x43f, 0x43b, 0x435, 0x43d, 0x438, 0x435, 0x20, 0x438, 0x20, 0x43d, 0x430, 0x43a, 0x430, 0x437, 0x430, 0x43d, 0x438, 0x435`

I could not find any reference about it, but it looks like simply calling `imbue` is not enough. `imbue` it a method from `basic_ios` which is an ancestor of `cout` and `wcout`. It does act on numeric conversions, but on all my tests, it has no effect on the charset used for output.

By default, the locale used in a C++ (or C) program is ... the `C` locale which knows nothing about unicode. All printable ASCII characters (below 128) are outputted as is, and others are replaced with a `?`. It is exactly what your program does.

To make it work correctly, you have to select a locale that knows about unicode characters with `setlocale`. Once this is done, you can change the numeric conversion by calling `imbue`, and *as you selected a unicode charset* all will be fine.

So provided your current locale uses an UTF-8 charset, you only have to add

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

as first line in your program, and the output will be as expected :

```
0: "Преступление"
1: "и"
2: "наказание"

I counted 3 words.
and the last word was "наказание"
```

If your current locale does not use UTF-8, choose one that is installed on you system and that supports it. I used `setlocale(LC_ALL, "fr_FR.UTF-8");`, or even `setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");` and both worked.

Edit :

In fact, the best way to correctly output unicode to screen is to use `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");`. It automatically adapts to the current charset. I tested with a stripped down variant using Latin1 charset (my system speaks natively french and not russian ...)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    wchar_t ws[] = { 0xe8, 0xe9, 0 };

    wcout << ws << endl;
}
```

I tried it under Linux using UTF-8 charset and ISO-8859-1 (latin1) (resp `export LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8` and `export LANG=fr_FR.ISO-8859-1`) and I got correctly `èé` in the proper charset. I tried it also under Windows XP, with codepage 851 (oem) and 1252 (ansi) (resp. `chcp 850` and `chcp 1252` with Lucida console charset), and got `èé` on the console too.

Edit 2 :

Of course, you can also set a global C++ locale with `locale::global(locale("");` with default locale or `locale::global(locale("ru_RU.UTF-8");` with russian locale, but it is more than simply calling `setlocale`. According to the documentation of Gnu implementation of C++ Standard Library about [locale](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/localization.html#std.localization.locales) : *there is only one relation (of the C++ locale mechanism) to the C locale mechanism: the global C locale is modified if a named C++ locale object is set as the global locale", that is: `std::locale::global(std::locale(""));` affects the C functions as if the following call was made: `std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "");`. On the other hand, there is no vice versa, that is, calling setlocale has no whatsoever on the C++ locale mechanism, in particular on the working of locale("")*.

So it really looks like there was an underlying C library mechanizme that should be first enabled with `setlocale` to allow `imbue` conversion to work correctly.

Comment: I appreciate your effort.  Unfortunately, it seems to me that `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` is not substantially different from the `locale::global(ru);` that I had in the original code.

Comment: Life Saver! `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` works!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what languages you're planning on supporting, but there are languages where your algorithm doesn't apply, eg. Japanese. I suggest checking out the word iterators in International Components for Unicode. http://userguide.icu-project.org/boundaryanalysis